# Controlled value on unknown quantity of inputs? React hook forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, checkbox, react-hook-form

I have a table of user permissions that I want to be able to manage through Controllers of React Hook Forms, the table itself looks like this:

[image: User permissions table]

(Right now, the permissions are randomly generated, hence the weird values)

Those permissions are dynamically added through an API Backend service, meaning that they're not static, some super user can generate a permission table for "Subject A", for example, with its own atomic permissions and it will be added dynamically on the screen shown above.

My problem here is that, when I change some checkbox value, the error "A component is changing the uncontrolled checked state of SwitchBase to be controlled." pops up, this happens, I guess, because I have not defined the defaultValues from my checkboxes, but I can't do it because I have no way of telling how many Subjects-Permissions are going to be in the future. Is there a way to fix this? Or perhaps, is my approach wrong?

I have the following code:

My whole form, i put it on a custom component that only renders a Dialog Modal.

```js
import { Box } from '@mui/material'
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { FormProps } from './FormPassword'
import PermissionBox from './PermissionBox'
import { getPermisos } from '@/services/usuarios'
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form'

const FormPermissions = (props: FormProps) => {
    const { idUser } = props;
    const [permisos, setPermisos] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getPermisos(idUser).then(res => {
            setPermisos(res.data);
        })
    }, []);

    const methods = useForm();

    const { control, handleSubmit } = methods;

    const changePermissions = (data: any) => {
        ///TODO change permissions
        console.log(data);
    }

    return (
        <Box
            component='form'
            id={props.id}
            sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'row',
                flexWrap: 'wrap',
                justifyContent: 'space-around',
                gap: '1rem',
                p: '10px',
                alignItems: 'center'
            }}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit(changePermissions)}
        >
            {
                permisos && permisos.map((permiso: any, idx: number) => (
                    <PermissionBox key={idx} permiso={permiso} idUser={idUser} control={control} />
                ))
            }
        </Box>
    )
}

export default FormPermissions
```

The individual component of each Subject and its permissions, used to render N quantity of tables with the corresponding permissions

```js
const PermissionBox = (props: PermissionBoxProps) => {

    const { permiso } = props;

    const [manage, ...actions] = permiso.actions.toReversed();

    return (
        <Grid
            item
            xs={2}
            sx={{
                display: 'flex',
                flexDirection: 'column',
                border: 1,
                p: 1,
            }}
        >
            <Typography variant='h6'>
                {permiso.subject}
            </Typography>
            <Divider sx={{
                margin: '0px -10px 0px -10px',
                borderBottomWidth: 2
            }}
            />

            {
                manage && (
                    <FormGroup>
                        <FormControlLabel
                            label={traduceAction(manage.action)}
                            control={
                                <Checkbox
                                    checked={manage.checked}
                                    indeterminate={isIndeterminated(actions, manage)}
                                />
                            }
                        />
                    </FormGroup>
                )
            }

            {
                actions && actions.map((action, index) => {
                    return (
                        <FormGroup key={index} sx={{
                            ...(action.action != 'manage' && { ml: 2 }),
                        }}>
                            <Controller
                                name={`permisos.${props.idUser}.${permiso.subject}.${action.id}`}
                                control={props.control}
                                render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                                    <FormControlLabel
                                        label={traduceAction(action.action)}
                                        control={
                                            <Checkbox
                                                checked={value}
                                                onChange={onChange}
                                                indeterminate={isIndeterminated(actions, manage)}
                                            />
                                        }
                                    />
                                )}
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    )
                })
            }
        </Grid>
    )
};
```